# Scanf in C explanation

Tags: c, scanf

It is me again. Today with very strange question. I was wondering about this for too long, so I am asking you to explain it to me.

Basically when we use:
`int a,b;
scanf("%d%d",a,b);`
We can put 2 numbers in it, but when someone wants to separate them by comma I will get an error. How can I write code where I will be able to write for example: 2,4 instead of 2 4? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Obligatory reminder: check the return value of `scanf`! In this case it should return 2, and if it returns less you have a problem (which you can trivially solve by `puts("scanf error!"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` if you don't want to add real error handling).

Comment: 'scanf("%d%d",a,b);' cannot modify a or b.

Comment: the code could prompt the user as to how to correctly enter the two numbers.  If the user enters something different, output an error message to stderr, cleanup, and exit the program.  It is not (normally) the concern of the program to compensate for a user formatting mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sometimes the integers are separated by space and sometimes by something else, strpbrk can be used to find the start of the integer and strtol to parse the integer. Use fgets to read an entire line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char line[900] = {'\0'};
    char *start = NULL;
    char *next = NULL;
    int array[10] = { 0};
    int each = 0;
    int loop = 0;

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), stdin)) {//read a line
        line[strcspn ( line, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline
        if ( line[0] == '\0') {
            break;//exit loop on blank line
        }
        each = 0;
        next = line;
        do {
            start = strpbrk ( next, "0123456789");//find start of number
            if ( start) {
                array[each] = strtol ( start, &next, 10);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
            each++;
            if ( each >= 10) {//too many numbers in line
                break;
            }
        } while ( *next != '\0');

        // show the values
        for(loop = 0; loop < each; loop++) {
            printf("[%d] ", array[loop]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nDone\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guys thanks so far. You helped me a lot. All 3 comments.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `,` between specifiers

```
scanf("%d,%d",&a, &b);
```

Your input should be `2,4`. `scanf` will read first integer then skip `,` and finally will read second integer.

Comment: It may well do, but not into a or b.

Comment: @MartinJames; Yeah. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want to allow it to be also a different symbol than comma, you can use another variable of type char.

```
 int a, b;
 char symbol;
 scanf("%d %c%d", &a, &symbol, &b);
```

and then you can make sure that symbol is a comma, or anything else.

```
if(symbol != ','){
 return;
}
```

it's more useful when it can be more than just one symbol. Otherwise it's more efficient to use comma directly in scanf.